# ctypes function ptr as c_void_p

Tags: python, ctypes

Using ctypes (python3), I'm trying to convert a `_FuncPtr` object that should really be an identifier or of type `c_void_p`.

But using `cast` yields the wrong address while `in_dll` yields the correct one.

In the code below, using `p1` causes segfault while `p2` works as intended.
Why is this, and how do you properly convert a `_FuncPtr` to `c_void_p`?

```py
windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo( kCGWindowListOptionAll, kCGNullWindowID )

for _win in cfarray( windows ):
    print( _win )
    p1 = cast( Q.kCGWindowNumber, c_void_p )
    p2 = c_void_p.in_dll( Q, "kCGWindowNumber" )
    pid = CFDictionaryGetValue( _win, p2 )
    print( pid )
```

Comment: `Q.kCGWindowNumber` contains the symbol address, but you want the `void *` pointer that's actually at that address, so, if for some reason you can't use `in_dll`, then use either `cast(Q.kCGWindowNumber, POINTER(c_void_p)).contents` or `POINTER(c_void_p).from_buffer(Q.kCGWindowNumber).contents`.

Comment: `in_dll` works, but your first solution is cleaner =) thanks! If you want to, post it as an answer so that I can +1 it.

Comment: Using `from_buffer` might not seem as clean, but the implementation is actually much simpler. `cast` is implemented using an FFI call, and there's a lot of work setting that up. Of course the small difference is no big deal unless you're in a tight loop.

Comment: "clean"-ness was in reference to `in_dll`, thanks, `from_buffer` version works great!